# Connecting HDD in Dell Inspiron 7000 laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, dell-inspiron, pata

Which side I should connect IDE HDD in Dell CPX/CPI port ?
Where should missing pin be ?

IMHO I think it should be at bottom, how do you think ?

How it [looks](http://cs323728.vk.me/v323728187/7046/h-_ULuks07M.jpg)[image: newuser image]

Comment: If you refer to the laptop casing you may find the hard drive is only able to fit in one orientation.

Answer (score 0):

[This photo](http://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=27&zenid=898c99fde9eff662f7080cafdbe20b46) makes it clear that the connector is next to the outer casing of the laptop, and so if the HDD were connected in your photograph, the label side would face up, with the connector closer to the bottom of the HDD.